# Electron + React: open a given route in a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a simple Electron application using react based on the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

In my application, I want to open a new window and go to a url like `/#/console` or something similar. However, since there is a `file://` loader, it does not appear to work in any reasonable way

```
componentDidMount() {
  const proxy = window.open(`file://${path.resolve(__dirname, '../app.html')}`);
}
```

While this does open the window, it will not go to the appropriate location, because it will just bootstrap the app again, obviously leading to a problem where it will re-open another window continuously.

Is there a way to open a window at a particular route in electron with react?

Comment: Not sure if you need help with this anymore but couldn't you use 
`const ipc = eval("require('electron').ipcRenderer");`
`ipc.send('open_route');` and add a ipcMain listener to help you open a particular window with that route.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get to a specific route/page in Electron? I'm trying to do instead of this `"http://localhost:3000/#/somePath"` something like this `secondWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html#somePath"));` My core problem is that I just get a blank window in production